# Regular expression for extracting a parameter value

Tags: regex, jmeter

Given a HTTP response header contains the following parameter:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.pdf"
```

What's the regular expression in JMeter to extract the filename `myfile.pdf`? I've started with `filename=".*"` but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all you need to surround your regular expression with parentheses like:

   ```
   filename=(.*)
   ```

   so JMeter would know what exactly you are trying to capture. It will extract `"myfile.pdf"`
2. If you don't need the quotation marks - add them to your regular expression like:

   ```
   filename="(.*)"
   ```
3. Make sure you have:

   - Field to check: `Response Headers`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor configuration]

---

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet) (JMeter uses [Perl5-style regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions))

Comment: Though the answer from @tim-biegeleisen works perfectly fine I have chosen this as the answer because of the explanation.

Comment: If you read the JMeter documentation, you will see that this answer is not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="([^"]+)"
```

Explanation:

```
(      capture what follows
[^"]+  any non quote character, one or more times
)      stop capture
```